# Using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to get the output from `top`

Tags: java, shell, output, exec

I'd like run the `top -n 1` command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)` method and get the output of `top -n 1` into my Java program.

I've tried the standard way of getting a processes output with a `BufferedReader` and using the returned Processes `InputStream` but that returned no data.

I also tried the following...

```
        String path = "/home/user/Desktop/";
        String cmd = "#!/bin/sh\ntop -n 1 > " + path + "output";
        File shellCmd = new File(path + "topscript.sh");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(shellCmd);
        writer.write(cmd);
        writer.flush();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +x " + shellCmd.getAbsolutePath()); 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellCmd.getAbsolutePath());
```

Which creates the `shell script` and the output but the output is empty. However, if I then load up my `local shell` and run the `script` that the code above made, I get the correct output in the output file.

```
What's going wrong?
```

Comment: Do you get error output stream? like `p.getErrorStream()` and what's the content?

Comment: @chengpohi Ah I didn't know about that method. It gave me `TERM environment variable not set.`

Comment: @chengpohi So it fails to execute the script but it can create the script and then `chmod` it. How can it `chmod` it but can't run it?

Comment: because when you use ***Java*** to run a bash script, it will spawn a new shell to run it without env variables.

Comment: Consider using `top -n 1 -b` to make the output more text-file friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String cmd = "#!/bin/sh\ntop -n1 -b > " + path + "output";
    File shellCmd = new File(path + "topscript.sh");
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(shellCmd);
    writer.write(cmd);
    writer.flush();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +x " + shellCmd.getAbsolutePath());

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(shellCmd.getAbsolutePath());
    Map<String, String> enviornments = pb.environment();
    enviornments.put("TERM", "xterm-256color");
    Process process = pb.start();

    BufferedReader inputStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader errorStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    String str = inputStreamReader.readLine();
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(errorStreamReader.readLine());
```

Use ***ProcessBuilder*** with setting ***TERM*** variables.

and if want to redirect `top` to file. need to add `-b` option to avoid `error: initializing curses`.

Comment: You probably want to use `top -n 1 -b` to make the output more suitable for redirection to a file.

Comment: @Cinnam Thanks, without `-b` will cause `error: initializing curses`.